# codeigniter update quantity not working

Tags: codeigniter

quantity not update only If I add an item with the exact same options more than once to my cart, it replaces instead of increasing the qty of the existing item
This is cart view code

```
`<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<thead ><!-- Table head -->
<tr>
    <th class="active">Sl</th>
    <th class="active col-sm-4">Product</th>
    <th class="active col-sm-2">Real Price</th>
    <th class="active ">Qty</th>
    <th class="active ">Disc Price</th>
    <th class="active">Total</th>
    <th class="active">Action</th>

</tr>
</thead><!-- / Table head -->
<tbody><!-- / Table body -->
<?php $cart = $this->cart->contents() ;

?>
<?php $counter =1 ; ?>
<?php if (!empty($cart)): foreach ($cart as $item) : ?>

    <tr class="custom-tr">
        <td class="vertical-td">
            <?php echo  $counter ?>
        </td>
        <td class="vertical-td"><?php echo $item['name'] ?></td>
        <td class="vertical-td"><?php echo $item['pkprice'] ?></td>
        <td class="vertical-td">

            <input  type="text" name="qty" style="width: 50px" value="<?php echo $item['qty'] ?>" onblur ="order(this);" id="<?php echo 'qty'.$item['rowid'] ?>" class="form-control">

        </td>
        <td>


            <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo 'opt'.$item['rowid'] ?>" onclick="return price_checkbox(this)" name="custom_price"
                             <?php echo $item['price_option'] == 'custom_price' ? 'checked':'' ?>
                             data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Custom Price">
                    </span>
                <input  type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo $item['price'] ?>"  onblur ="order(this);" id="<?php echo 'pri'.$item['rowid'] ?>" class="form-control"
                        <?php echo $item['price_option'] == 'custom_price' ? '':'disabled' ?> >
            </div>


            <input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="<?php echo $item['id']  ?>" id="<?php echo 'code'.$item['rowid'] ?>">
        </td>
        <td class="vertical-td"><?php echo number_format($item['subtotal'], 2, '.', ',')  ?></td>

        <td class="vertical-td">
            <?php echo btn_delete('admin/order/delete_cart_item/' . $item['rowid']); ?>
        </td>

    </tr>


    <?php
    $counter++;
endforeach;
    ?><!--get all sub category if not this empty-->





<?php else : ?> <!--get error message if this empty-->
    <td colspan="6">
        <strong>There is no record for display</strong>
    </td><!--/ get error message if this empty-->
<?php endif; ?>
</tbody><!-- / Table body -->
```

`

This is Controller Code

```
public function add_cart_item_by_barcode(){

    $product_code = $this->input->post('barcode', true);
    $result = $this->order_model->validate_add_cart_item($product_code);



    if($result){





        $price = $this->check_product_rate($result->product_id, $qty=1);

        //product tax check
        $tax = $this->product_tax_calculate($result->tax_id, $qty=1, $price);

        $data = array(
            'id' => $result->product_code,
            'qty' => 1,
            'price' => $price,
            'buying_price' => $result->buying_price,
            'name' => $result->product_name,
            'pkprice' => $result->p_price,
            'tax' => $tax,
            'price_option' => 'general'
        );
        $this->cart->update($data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('cart_msg', 'add');
    }

    redirect('admin/order/new_order/'.$flag ='add');
}

public function check_product_rate($product_id=null, $qty=null)
{
    //tier Price check
    $tire_price = $this->order_model->get_tire_price($product_id, $qty);

    if($tire_price)
    {
        return $price = $tire_price->tier_price ;
    }

    //special offer check
    $this->tbl_special_offer('special_offer_id');
    $offer_price = $this->global_model->get_by(array("product_id"=>$product_id), true);

    if(!empty($offer_price)) {
        $today = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
        $start_date = strtotime($offer_price->start_date);
        $end_date = strtotime($offer_price->end_date);
        if (($today >= $start_date) && ($today <= $end_date)) {
            return $price = $offer_price->offer_price;
        }
    }

    //return regular rate
    $this->tbl_product_price('product_price_id');
    $general_price = $this->global_model->get_by(array("product_id"=>$product_id), true);
    return $product_price = $general_price->selling_price;

}

/*** Product tax calculation ***/
public function product_tax_calculate($tax_id, $qty ,$price)
{
    $this->tbl_tax('tax_id');
    $tax = $this->global_model->get_by(array('tax_id'=>$tax_id), true);

    //1 = tax in %
    //2 = Fixed tax Rate

    if($tax){
        if($tax->tax_type == 1)
        {
            $subtotal = $price * $qty;
            $product_tax = $tax->tax_rate * ($subtotal / 100);

            //return $result = round($product_tax, 2);
            return $result = $product_tax;

        }else
        {

            //$product_tax = $tax->tax_rate * $qty;
            $product_tax = $tax->tax_rate * $qty;
            return $result = $product_tax;

        }
    }
}

/*** Update Product Cart ***/
public function update_cart_item()
{
    $rowid = $this->input->post('rowid');
    $qty = $this->input->post('qty');
    $product_price = $this->input->post('price');
    $product_code = $this->input->post('product_code');
    $custom_price = $this->input->post('custom_price');


    if($qty !=0 )
    {
        //tbl product
        $this->tbl_product('product_id');
        $result = $this->global_model->get_by(array('product_code'=> $product_code ), true);

        //product Inventory Check
        $this->tbl_inventory('inventory_id');
        $product_inventory = $this->global_model->get_by(array('product_id'=> $result->product_id ), true);

        if($qty > $product_inventory->product_quantity)
        {
            $type = 'error';
            $message = 'Sorry! This product has not enough stock.';
            set_message($type, $message);
            echo 'false';
            return;
        }


        if($custom_price == "on")
        {
               $price = $product_price;
               $price_option = 'custom_price';

        }
        else
        {
            //product price check
            $price = $this->check_product_rate($result->product_id, $qty);
            $price_option = 'general';
        }


        //product tax check
        $tax = $this->product_tax_calculate($result->tax_id, $qty, $price);



        $data = array(
            'rowid' => $rowid,
            'qty' => $qty,
            'price' => $price,
            'tax'   => $tax,
            'price_option' => $price_option

        );
    }else
    {
        $data = array(
            'rowid' => $rowid,
            'qty' => $qty,
        );
    }

    $this->cart->update($data);

    if($this->input->post('ajax') != '1'){
        redirect('admin/order/new_order'); // If javascript is not enabled, reload the page with new data
    }else{
        echo 'true'; // If javascript is enabled, return true, so the cart gets updated
    }
}
/*** Show cart ***/
function show_cart(){
    $this->load->view('admin/order/cart/cart');
}
/*** cart Summery ***/
function show_cart_summary(){
    $this->load->view('admin/order/cart/cart_summary');
}


/*** Delete Cart Item ***/
public function delete_cart_item($id)
{
    $data = array(
        'rowid' => $id,
        'qty' => 0,
    );
    $this->cart->update($data);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('cart_msg', 'delete');
    redirect('admin/order/new_order/'.$flag ='delete');
}
```

This is working fine when add product or change its quantity all perfect working but If I add an item with the exact same options more than once to my cart, it replaces instead of increasing the qty of the existing item

Comment: do you get some errors?

Comment: no error getting just product add again and qty still 1

Comment: do you just inserting data? `$this->cart->insert($data);`

Comment: yes all code working fine $this->cart->insert($data);  but qty not increased when add product again by barcode

Comment: you should use `update`, but you're using `insert` instead!

Comment: how can i use update method in my (product add to cart by barcode) controller

Comment: do you need to update quantity of your product or you want insert new product?

Comment: i need update quantity right now the add new product working fine

Comment: read this: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/cart.html#updating-the-cart

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
<?php foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $items): ?>

<?php echo form_hidden($counter.'[rowid]', $items['rowid']); ?> // write this
```

and then this

```
<td><?php echo form_input(array('name' => $counter.'[qty]', 'value' => $items['qty'], 'maxlength' => '3', 'size' => '5')); ?></td>
```

instead of-

```
<?php echo form_input(array('name' =>'rowid1[]', 'type'=>'text', 'value' => $items['rowid'], 'maxlength' => '3', 'size' => '5')); ?>
```

I hope this works

Comment: when i add product to cart then product add successfully and its qty 1 but when i add same product again then qty not increased its still 1

Comment: I think the problem is with form_input(), can you write it in normal html or change normal html inputs to form inputs?

Comment: i update the code now please solve the problem i tried near one week but not success

Comment: have you tried running it again? after code change?

Comment: foreach($this->cart->contents() as $item){
    if($item['id'] == 'your_product_id'){
        $item['qty'] = 3;
        $this->cart->update($item);
    }
}

Comment: Still not updating quantity

Comment: You need to do cart update by doing loop on cart contents because CI will always create unique row_id on each insert.

Comment: public function update_cart_item() in this function print and see the values of qty and row id, and see if you need to pass it in if else loops  of product price check and product tax check, we can't debug your code, you'll need to figure it out yourself now

Answer (score 0):

Check what query is generated when update query is fire, i think any signal quote is added in your query.
for check the last database query use this function:-
print_r($this->db->last_query());

Comment: SELECT tbl_product.*, tbl_inventory.product_quantity, tbl_inventory.notify_quantity
FROM (`tbl_product`)
LEFT JOIN `tbl_inventory` ON `tbl_inventory`.`product_id`  =  `tbl_product`.`product_id` 
WHERE `tbl_product`.`status` =  1
ORDER BY `tbl_product`.`product_id`  DESC        This is generated

Comment: hello shoaib, i am just want to look what query is generated when you fire your update query.

Comment: in my public function add_cart_item_by_barcode there is no update query i never understand that how i am use it if item already in cart how to update its quantity in public function add_cart_item_by_barcode all code is working fine but no any idea that how make update query in public function add_cart_item_by_barcode.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of struggled i get my code correctly here is the correct code of insert and update

```
function add_cart_item_by_barcode(){

$product_code = $this->input->post('barcode', true);
$result = $this->order_model->validate_add_cart_item($product_code);

$rowid = $this->input->post('rowid');
$cart = $this->cart->contents();

foreach ($cart as $cart) {

       if($product_code == $cart['id']){

            $rowid=$cart['rowid'];
            $qty=$cart['qty'];


                    $data=array(
                    'rowid'=>$rowid,
                    'qty'=>$qty+1
                    );

        $data=$this->cart->update($data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('cart_msg', 'add');
        redirect('admin/order/new_order/'.$flag ='add');

                    }
                }
if ($result) {  

// update rate
        $price = $this->check_product_rate($result->product_id, $qty=1);

        //product tax check
        $tax = $this->product_tax_calculate($result->tax_id, $qty=1, $price);

        $data = array(
            'id' => $result->product_code,
            'qty' => $qty,
            'price' => $price,
            'buying_price' => $result->buying_price,
            'name' => $result->product_name,
            'pkprice' => $result->p_price,
            'tax' => $tax,
            'price_option' => 'general'
        );
        $this->cart->insert($data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('cart_msg', 'add');
}   

redirect('admin/order/new_order/'.$flag ='add');
                      }
```